# What could be the cause of the smearing and ghosting displayed below?

Tags: kde5, plasma5

My system's graphic display has developed some kind of ghosting and smearing problem. It is a Plasma 5 desktop running Siduction, a variant of Debian Stretch/Sid. The title bars are normal and although it isn't shown the panel at the bottom of the screen and the titles on it are alright. What could be the problem?

I've also noticed that although it is present on Konsole and Kate it doesn't appear on Geany and Xterm and it could be related to the screen refresh routines used by KDE/Qt as opposed to the Gtk used by the later. Does anyone have some experience with this kind of problem.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/wWjOrnP.jpg]

[image: https://i.imgur.com/xMSvVYL.jpg]

Comment: Are those photographs of your screen, or captured screenshots?  If the former, can you provide the latter?

Comment: They are captured screenshots

Comment: It turns out there some kernel and driver related conflicts and it was solved after I did some more upgrades and installs

Comment: It might be helpful for you to move your comment to an Answer (as it was the solution for your problem), so that others searching for this issue can see what worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that an some dist-upgrades and upgrade I did earlier did not update the kernel properly. There was some mismatch between the kernel and the drivers present.

After upgrading the kernel and running some updates and upgrades the problem was solved.